# Checking Firestore property value before updating

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The problem i can't seem to solve is:

I want to update a the value of a property in one of my collections lets say i have  a collection "posts" and all the documents have a property(field) of votes which buy default is 1 and i want to update by one by every click.

collection       doc          fields

posts            id1          votes: 1

Updating the value is would look something like this:

```
  addVote(id){
    this.postCollection.doc(id).update({
      votes: 2
    })
  }
```

But how would I go about if I first want to check the the value of the property and then increase it by one for each click, the firebase documentation isn't much help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the documentation is of help here.  You will need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) for changes that involve getting, modifying, and setting a value in a document.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, i should have looked more!